# How to make 'git pull' take a message?

Tags: git, git-pull

Well, here we go again with more Git goodness. It has found other ways to make simple tasks difficult to impossible...

```
git pull -X theirs https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp.git master
From https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
Auto-merging GNUmakefile
error: cannot spawn notepad++.exe: No such file or directory
error: unable to start editor 'notepad++.exe'
Not committing merge; use 'git commit' to complete the merge.
```

`notepad++.exe` is where nearly every other Windows executable is located. Its in program files. Its not a secret, and its not a hidden location.

Try again so it stops wasting my time with useless crap:

```
# Rewind past broken git
git checkout HEAD~3 -f

# Back to master
git checkout master -f

# Tray again; avoid the prompt
$ git pull -X theirs -m "Sync with Upstream master" https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp.git master
error: unknown switch `m'
usage: git pull [<options>] [<repository> [<refspec>...]]

    -v, --verbose         be more verbose
    -q, --quiet           be more quiet
    --progress            force progress reporting
```

What is the option to tell Git, *"Here's the message to use. Stop confusing yourself. Stop wasting my time with useless crap?"*

Thanks in advance

Comment: `git pull` is a bad tool. I recommend avoiding it. Run `git fetch` with the fetch arguments, then run `git merge` with the merge arguments. You can supply your own message properly here. The `--no-edit` thing works with both `git pull` and `git merge` but if you make an explicit separate step you get much more control and visibility.

Comment: Seems the path of `notepad++.exe` is not right in `git config`.

Comment: Can you do `git config core.editor` and tell us what it says?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can't provide your own message, but the `--no-edit` option passed to `git pull` will auto-generate merge messages.

`git pull --no-edit`

Comment: Thanks @glukki. *"You can't provide your own message..."* - Well, that's not surprising. Its like this tool goes out of its way to make things difficult. 45 minutes wasted trying to perform this simple task...

Comment: Well, there might be some sort of the solution: you could set a script that returns a predefined text (a merge commit message) as a system editor during `git pull` with an `EDITOR` environment variable

Answer (score 9):

While you cannot do it with one command, you can easily do it with two:

```
git pull --no-edit  &&  git commit --amend -m "my new message"
```

Answer (score 1):

According to official `git` documentation, you can use `--no-commit` option or else if it is a fast-forward merge, then you must use `no-ff` with `no-commit`.

> With `--no-commit` perform the merge and stop just before creating a merge commit, to give the user a chance to inspect and further tweak the merge result before committing. Note that `fast-forward` updates do not create a merge commit and therefore there is no way to stop those merges with --no-commit. Thus, if you want to ensure your branch is not changed or updated by the merge command, use `--no-ff` with `--no-commit`.